# Find All References of a Method Using Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

I want to find the location of all method calls to a single class at runtime. I'm using reflection, but I cannot find a way to locate where it is being used. For example:

```
public class Test 
{
   public void Method1()
   { 
     // do something 
   }
   public void Method2()
   {
     Method2();
   }
}
```

I want to find at runtime Method2 is called by Method1. Is there a way?

I think there should be, as Visual Studio can do it via "Find All References". Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible .Visual Studio does not use Reflection to do that.

Comment: You want to use the .NET Compiler Platform API for this.  Reflection is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you'd need to parse the method body of the methods you're looking at, see this[^]. It might help you get started.

Btw, if you're doing this within a Visual Studio macro, I believe VS provides some objects that might be of use to doing this without IL parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be

```
public void Method1()
{
    Method2();
}
public void Method2()
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    string name = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
    Console.WriteLine(name);
   //do something
}


Test test = new Test();
test.Method1(); // write "Method1"
```